# Make new clients play in their own scene

Tags: unity, mirror-networking

I'm building a game where a single player fights waves of mobs to earn a high score.

I'd like to use mirror to add server authority.

In the first instance this looks like a single player game. So rather than Clients playing together they will play separately but be connected to a host.

When a new client joins how can I put them into their own "instance" of the scene?

Edit:

The main reason I want server authority is to make a leaderboard and to persist earned gold. Each time you kill an enemy you get some points and the enemy drops gold. I want to keep track of the gold a user has earned as well as their points.

Comment: If you just need server verification and logging, then I think Mirror will be overkill for your needs, and you could do it in a more scalable way. If you'd like to explore that, try editing your question to show an example of the kind of mechanic you want to add server authority to.

Comment: If you still want to use mirror (maybe for practise), there is an available example with the room component: https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/examples/room - you could set the room to one person and autostart and the player would not even notice the room. If in the future two or more can play together in a level (maybe displaying ghosts where all are doing the same level but with no interaction), you have already the matching done as well

Comment: Thanks I will look at mirror rooms. @DMGregory I have added a bit about the mechanic I'd like to add server authority to. I want gold and earned points to be controlled by the server, so a player cannot cheat.

Comment: Keep in mind that there mind be a limit on how many enemies you can have at the same time and still get smooth sync if you plan to fight waves of enemies (in case you have a game in mind like the typical `Surviver` one).

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing @Zibelas

Comment: @Zibelas I have begun setting up Mirror rooms. I've got a dedicated server running and can connect clients to it, but want to make it so if there is 1 client already connected then create a new room and start immediately. Any ideas?

Comment: You can set a maximum amount of people per room. And you probably dont need everything in the network room manager. I would not autostart the game right away, but nobody said that the ready button has to be really a ready button. It could be just as well a character selection und the ready button is a confirm choice button